# Python: Group list of objects based on id and timeframe

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, group-by, python-itertools

I am working with a list of objects which has sys_id and datetime as two of its fields. I would like to group these objects based on sys_id and datetime if the time gap between each object is less than 5 minutes.

For instance, if my data is

test_id sys_id  time

1   11  1/1/2018 6:03

2   11  1/1/2018 6:07

3   11  1/1/2018 6:11

4   11  1/1/2018 6:14

5   12  1/2/2018 15:25

6   12  1/3/2018 15:30

7   12  1/4/2018 15:33

8   12  1/5/2018 15:37

I would like to group test_ids 01,02,03,04 as one list as they have same sys_id and time gap between each of the tests is less than 5 minutes and test_ids 05,06,07,08 as another group.

Comment: Please post your dataframe as text (not an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your records by time first. Then iterate through the records and append them to the last sub-list of the output list if the time difference to the last entry is no more than 5 minutes; otherwise put the record into a new sub-list of the output list.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
data = [
    {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:00'},
    {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:03'},
    {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:07'},
    {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:11'},
    {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:25'},
    {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:30'},
    {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:33'},
    {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 6:37'},
]
def to_time(string):
    return datetime.strptime(string, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
data.sort(key=lambda record: to_time(record['time']))
output = []
for record in data:
    if output and to_time(record['time']) - to_time(output[-1][-1]['time']) <= timedelta(minutes=5):
        output[-1].append(record)
    else:
        output.append([record])
print(output)
```

This outputs (after formatting):

```
[
    [{'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:00'}, {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:03'}, {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:07'}, {'sys_id': 11, 'time': '1/1/18 6:11'}],
    [{'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 6:37'}],
    [{'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:25'}, {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:30'}, {'sys_id': 12, 'time': '1/1/18 15:33'}]
]
```